# android viewbadger prroblem with android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to use [android-viewbadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) library in my project but when I use it in android 6.0 the badger go behind my view:

[image]

what is the problem?

Comment: By the way, this library is `DEPRECATED`. Last commit 4 years ago...

Comment: @Kevinrob Is there any alternative to this library?

Comment: I don't know, sorry!